# Finding all possible permutations of a start/end index in Array

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

I'm attempting to write a method that returns the maximum value that can be obtained by elements of a subArray in Swift.

The problem I'm running into creating an algorithm which captures all possible permutations of the beginning and ending indeces of the `ArraySlice`s I run through the `sliceSum` method.

I know the solution is something simple, but I'm unable to figure it out. I welcome suggestions re: how I can accomplish my goal of running all possible permutations through the `sliceSum` method.

```
func maxSubArray(_ nums: [Int]) -> Int {
    var output = 0

    func sliceSum(slice: ArraySlice<Int>) -> Int {
        // throws out cases that don't work
        guard slice.count > 0 || slice.count != nums.count else { return 0 }
        return slice.reduce(0, +)
    }

    var begin = 0
    var end = nums.count - 1

    while begin < end {
        let frontSlice = nums[begin...end]
        if sliceSum(slice: frontSlice) > output {
            output = sliceSum(slice: frontSlice)
        }

        begin += 1
        end -= 1
    }

    return output
}
```

Given the following, I should be returning 6, which is the sum of slice `[4,-1,2,1]` in the following array:

```
let array = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
maxSubArray(array)
```

Thank you for reading. I welcome your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your goal, you need two loops. Replace your `while` loop and the `begin` and `end` variables with:

```
for begin in 0..<nums.count {
    for end in begin..<nums.count {
        let frontSlice = nums[begin...end]
        let sum = sliceSum(slice: frontSlice)
        if sum > output {
            output = sum
        }
    }
}
```

I'd also redo your `sliceSum` to be:

```
func sliceSum(slice: ArraySlice<Int>) -> Int {
    if slice.count > 0 {
        return slice.reduce(0, +)
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved 198 of 202 test cases. Looks like this is a job best suited for Kadane's algorithm, which I just learned about. Once I figure out how to write this in Swift, I'll post an update. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem